# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Record URL Wrong

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've created a workflow that will send a user an email that contains the URL for the entity.  Somehow it's putting the wrong URL (specifically subdomain is wrong).

Does anybody know if there is a setting that controls this and what it is?

Comment: Is this issue got fixed? I have the similar problem. Instead of Domain Name I am getting IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the server URL from the setting in Deployment Manager, as far as I know. If in DM you specify the server URL as:

```
mycrmserver:5555
```

this may cause an issue. Using a FQDN will probably give better results:

```
mycrmserver.mydomain.com:5555
```

But obviously make sure you have DNS on your domain pointing to the internal LAN IP of that for internal clients (using mycrmserver.internal.local style FQDN won't work if you need IFD)
I'm not 100% sure this will fix it, but certainly worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Open Deployment Manager -> Right Click on Microsoft Dynamics CRM -> Properties -> Select Web Address tab -> Make sure that the domain name specified under Web Application Server is correct

[image]